# Returning Integers to Base 6

Tags: radix

Working to the base 6, what is that is the result of the product 3 * 5?

Is anyone able to answer this for me. I've been stuck for hours and still can't figure it out. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Base 10:
`3 * 5 = 15`

To convert to Base 6, `15 / 6 = 2 r 3`, so the result is `23`. It is simple counting (`5 + 5 = 5 + 1 + 4 = 10 + 4 = 14; 14 + 5 = 10 + 4 + 2 + 3 = 10 + 10 + 3 = 23`; all in base six). Programmatically you do this by doing integer division (you get the quotient) and then you do mod 6 (to get the remainder) and sum them.

As for a more mathematical explanation, in base 10 we increment the carry after 9 and decrement it if we move before zero. The same logic applies with base 6, we increment the carry after 5 and decrement if we move before zero. That is why I broke everything out so that we get sums that add up to 6, because that indicates the carry.